# Google+ new UI does not allow to share posts in LinkedIn

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

Did you notice that Google+ new user interface is lacking the ability
to share posts on LinkedIn?

Do you know if there is something I need to do to allow it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google+ never had the ability to share posts to LinkedIn.

I suspect that you have a chrome extension that provided this functionality, like Extended Share.  The updated UI may require an update to the extension.